# Обработка группы изображений перед выводом в foreach

Tags: php, json

есть json

```
   {"streams":[ 
   {"channel":{"name":"1","tiltle":"2","alt":"3"}},
   {"channel":{"name":"a","tiltle":"b","alt":"c"}} ]}
```

обратывает его простой php командой foreach
и подгружая файлы. получается:

```
   <img src="server/1.jpg" alt="2" title="3" /><br>
   <img src="server/a.jpg" alt="b" title="c" /><br>
```

иногда картинки 1.jpg или a.jpg (по разному) нет. И толгда вместо нее сервер отдает 404.jpg
получается

```
   <img src="server/404.jpg" alt="2" title="3" /><br>
   <img src="server/a.jpg" alt="b" title="c" /><br>
```

Надо сделать: если картинка заменяется на 404.jpg то ее ставило всегда в конец:

```
   <img src="server/a.jpg" alt="b" title="c" /><br>
   <img src="server/404.jpg" alt="2" title="3" /><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Внутри цикла заполняйте два массива: найденных и отсутствующих картинок.

А потом формтируйте вывод – сначала найденных, потом 404.

```
<?php
$found = array();    // здесь будут теги с найденными картинками
$missing = array();  // а здесь – с 404
foreach( $streams AS $c=>$channel) {
  if( file_exists( sprintf( "/var/www/server/%s.jpg", $channel['name'])) {
    array_push( $found, sprintf(
      '<img src="server/%s.jpg" alt="%s" title="%s" /><br />',
      $channel['name'],
      $channel['alt'],
      $channel['title']
    ));
  } else {
    array_push( $missing, sprintf(
      '<img src="server/%s.jpg" alt="%s" title="%s" /><br />',
      "404",
      $channel['alt'],
      $channel['title']
    ));
  }
}
// а теперь вывод
echo impode( "\n", $found);
echo impode( "\n", $missing);
```

Comment: А можно код, не силен в массивах

Comment: Пример кода добавил в ответ.

Comment: Код можно намного лучше написать, если быть уверенным, что всегда в stream только два channel; что отсутствовать может не более 1 из 2 картинок и пр.

Comment: тут стоит отметить, что картинки не на локальном сервере, и проверка проходит - картинка если есть - то ок, а если нет он подменяет ее 404_preview-640x360.jpg

Comment: насчёт удалённого сервера **стоило** отметить в вопросе. В таком случае лучше всё это делать на клиенте, на JavaScript, а не на PHP/серевере.